# Is it possible to get the original file path of the file user uploaded through POST in PHP?

Tags: php, http, post

I am not sure if I phrased the question correctly, but this is what I wish to achieve:

1. Create a form which allows user to upload an image (HTML code)
2. User uploads an image that is, say, stored in C:/Users/path/to/image.jpg in their computer
3. When they click the upload button, "C:/Users/path/to/image.jpg" is printed

I have tried `echo($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);` but it prints out the path of the uploaded file which is temporarily stored after the upload script is run. (i.e. it prints out something like: `C:/xampp/randomname.tmp` with the `tmp` extension)

I understand that with the PHP script, the uploaded file is first stored in a temporary directory before relocated to the target location (as mentioned here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm). However, what I want is the **actual file path in the user's computer**. Can anyone please tell me if this is possible? Or how to work around it?

*form.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*upload.php*

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $file = $_FILES['file'];

   $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
   $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
   $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

   $fileExt = explode('.',$fileName);
   $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

   $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png');

   if (in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('',true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = "C:/Desktop/".$fileNameNew; //'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination);

                echo($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);  
            } 
            else {
                echo "File is too big";
            }
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error occurred";
        }
   } 
   else {
       echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the filepath on the users PC? If so NO

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes. So this is not possible with other scripts as well? Like Django?

Comment: I would not expect any Server based code to be allowed to know that. Its completely irrelevant and could even be considered a data leak if it was possible.

Comment: It is not possible for the same reason that JavaScript cannot just traverse the clients file-system and look at what ever files it wants.  This is one of the major areas of sand-boxing in the browser. You can get [some information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) about the file from JavaScript, but it is fairly limited.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need that path? Maybe there's another way to do what you're trying to do with the path.

Comment: If the file type is important you need to look at the contents of the file itself not the name.  I can rename any file to any extension I want, an executable to .txt, a PNG to JPG, cat to dog, ...